# Find substring in stream without storing substring in plain text

Tags: string, algorithm

Lets say I have a large stream of data (for example packets coming in from a network), and I want to determine if this data contains a certain substring. There are multiple [string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), but they require the algorithm to know the plain text string they are searching for.

Lets say, the string being sought is a password, and you do not want to store it in plain text in this search application. It would however appear in the stream as plain text. You could for example, store the hash and length of the password. Then for every byte in the stream check if the next length byte data from the stream hash to the password hash you have a probable match.

That way you can determine if the password was in the stream, without knowing the password. However, hashing once for every byte is not fast/efficient.

Is there perhaps a clever algorithm that could find the plain text password in the stream, without directly knowing the plain text password (and instead some non-reversible equivalent). Alternatively could a low quality version of the password be used, with the risk of false positives? For example, if the search application only knew half the password (in plain text), it could with some error detect the full password without knowing it.

thanks

P.S This question comes from a hypothetical discussion I had with some friends, about alerting you if your password was spotted in plain text on a network.

Comment: Even storing the hash of the password in memory might not be a good idea, since an attacker could steal the hash, then brute-force hash everything in a password dictionary and check the hashes against the hash of your password. Can you elaborate a bit about your security requirements? Are there particular things you expect that an attacker can and cannot do?

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking about finding (a) a *known* password that you wish to hide from someone who discovers your source code, or (b) an *unknown* password that matches some *known* pattern (if the pattern is also unknown, then there's no hope, since what stops an arbitrary sequence of bytes from being the password?).  These are quite separate questions.  The former can be "solved" by obfuscating the password sufficiently (e.g. by using multiple hash functions).  Depending on the type of pattern, the latter might be "solved" using approximate string matching.

Comment: @templatetypedef since this is hypothetical I have no strict security requirements.

Comment: @j_random_hacker option a. I know my password, but want to hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a low-entropy [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) to pre-screen each byte so that, for the cost of lg k bits of entropy, you reduce the number of invocations of the cryptographic hash by a factor of k.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. So hash my password to say a 16bit number (which hopefully is less entropy than my password), then using the rolling hash algorithm search for this 16 bit number. Once found, check with the more intensive crypto hash.

Comment: @bramp That's the idea, yes.

Answer (score 0):

[SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability) is an NP-hard problem.  Suppose your password is n characters long.  If you could find a way to make a large enough SAT instance that

- used a contiguous sequence of m >= n bytes from the data stream as its 8m input bits, and
- produced the output 1 if and only if the bits present at its inputs contains your password starting at an offset that is some multiple of 8 bits

then by "operating" this SAT instance as a circuit, you would have a password detector that is (at least potentially) very difficult to "invert".

In some ways, what you want is the opposite of [Boolean logic minimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions).  You want the biggest, hairiest circuit (ideally for some theoretically justified notions of size and hairiness :) ) that computes the truth table.  It's easy enough to come up with truth-table-preserving ways to grow the original CNF propositional logic formula -- e.g., if you have two clauses A and B, then you can always safely add a new clause consisting of all the literals in either A or B -- but it's probably much harder to come up with ways to grow the formula *in ways that will confuse a modern SAT solver*, since a lot of research has gone into making these programs super-efficient at detecting and exploiting all kinds of structure in the problem.

One possible avenue for injecting "complications" is to make the circuit compute functions that are difficult for circuits to compute, like divisions or square roots, and then test the results of these for equality in addition to the raw inputs.  E.g., instead of making the circuit merely test that `X[1 .. 8n] = YOUR_PASSWORD`, make it test that `X[1 .. 8n] = YOUR_PASSWORD AND sqrt(X[1 .. 8n]) = sqrt(YOUR_PASSWORD)`.  If a SAT solver is smart enough to "see" that the first test implies the second then it can immediately dispense with all the clauses corresponding to the second -- but since everything is represented at a very low level with propositional clauses, this relationship is (I hope; as I said, modern SAT solvers are pretty amazing) well obscured.  My guess is that it's *better* to choose functions like sqrt() that are not [one-to-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection#Injection) on integers: this will potentially cause a SAT solver to waste time exploring seemingly promising (but ultimately incorrect) solutions.